# Subquery count with union all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

My query selects data from 3 tables, sets the result as 'title' (one table has 'description' as the column I need to look in). I also create a result 'doctype' with a value denoting which table it was found in to use for front end filters later. It then orders by:

1. Result starts with searchterm
2. Result contains searchterm somewhere in the middle
3. Result ends with searchterm

What I need is to get the count for each of the subqueries within the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Title as title, 'docs' AS 'doctype' FROM docs 
    WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
UNION ALL
    SELECT Title as title, 'sheets' AS 'doctype' FROM sheets 
    WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
UNION ALL 
  SELECT Description AS title, 'pres' AS 'doctype' from presentations 
  WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Description LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
) FINAL
    ORDER BY
      CASE
        WHEN title LIKE :searchterm '%' THEN 1
        WHEN title LIKE '%' :searchterm THEN 3
        ELSE 2
      END
    LIMIT 300
```

And also for confirmation that it is OK to use the alias name ('title') in the ORDER BY.

Comment: Off the top of my head my solution would be to run those search terms separately and count that, but this is probably the worst way to do it ^.^

Comment: you cannot have both mysql and sql-server - please remove the extraneous tag.

Comment: thanks @Eli that's done

Answer (score 0):

Add a count field and a groupby clause in your subqueries

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(*) FROM docs WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%') as 'count_docs'
,(SELECT count(*) FROM sheets WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%') as 'count_sheets'
,(SELECT count(*) FROM presentations WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Description LIKE '%' :searchterm '%') as 'count_pres'
, FINAL.*
FROM (
    SELECT Title as title, 'docs' AS 'doctype' FROM docs 
    WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
UNION ALL
    SELECT Title as title, 'sheets' AS 'doctype' FROM sheets 
    WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Title LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
UNION ALL 
  SELECT Description AS title, 'pres' AS 'doctype' from presentations 
  WHERE status IN ('publish', 'draft', 'review') AND Description LIKE '%' :searchterm '%'
) as FINAL
    ORDER BY
      CASE
        WHEN title LIKE :searchterm '%' THEN 1
        WHEN title LIKE '%' :searchterm THEN 3
        ELSE 2
      END
    LIMIT 300
```

Comment: That's seems to be showing all results and with no error - but how do I access the 3 values? Each row now seems to come with a value 'cnt' of 1. Also, why is GROUP BY required?

Comment: @CIvemy I think I had it wrong the first time, try this updated one now instead. I cant test it myself so let me know if there are sql errors.
By the way the values of count_docs, count_sheets and count_pres will always be the same in all rows. So the result set will be redundant in that aspect.
Performance-wise, it would be better to have separate queries for this counting of totals.